# How to find out the name of the root element?

Tags: javascript, xml

Suppose I have downloaded a valid XML document via Ajax (var docum = request.responseXML;). Now how do I find out the name of the root element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
docum.documentElement.tagName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlDoc;
if (window.DOMParser) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(dataString, "text/xml");
} else {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(dataString);
}
xmlDoc.documentElement; // is what you need
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have a string with xml then this will give you the first tag

```
var xml = "<foo><bar>......";
var tag = /<(.*?)>/.exec(xml)[1];
alert(tag) // foo
```

Alternatively you just access the node and retrieves the tagName

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><foo><bar/></foo>`

Comment: Are you referring to what 'valid' XML is? If so then be aware that the `<?xml...?>` block is optional..

Comment: No, I mean your regex will show `?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?` as the tag name.